# Convert multiple image blocks to gallery block in Gutenberg?

Tags: images, gallery, block-editor

Its easy to convert a gallery block into multiple image blocks. But how do I do the reverse?

I have several older posts with a dozen or so images sequentially. I would like to display these all in a gallery block without searching the media library one at a time to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has been a while, but I found this page looking for the same answer. Once I discovered the solution, I thought I would share it here to help you or someone in the future.

Once you convert the classic to blocks, you can multi select the images, and then the convert button allows you to convert to a gallery.

I noticed mine stayed at thumbnail until I go to edit the gallery. I don't make any changes just save gallery, and then the images don't default to the thumbnail size any longer. This part may vary by user depending on how the images were initially added.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed this works! I didn't know I had to convert the post from Classic to Blocks first -- probably why the answer eluded me in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold SHIFT and mark all individual images
2. Scroll up to the first image
3. Convert the Image Block to a Gallery Block

This will add all selected images into the Gallery Block.